# Why shouldn't I disable legacy USB on a laptop?

Tags: usb, bios

By default the BIOS enables this feature.
What are the advantages of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling it made the USB boot to stop working

Comment: Ah, i was just going to point you to: [USB Keyboard won't work after Post but before OS loads](http://superuser.com/questions/207963/usb-keyboard-wont-work-after-post-but-before-os-loads)

Answer (score 3):

This [link](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/usbcompat.mspx#EID) is admittedly very old, but i can not imagine that the function in the BIOS has changed much. Essentially what the Legacy USB Support in the BIOS does is emulate USB Keyboards and Mice as PS/2 compatible devices, enabling operating systems which are not USB aware to accept them as input devices.

Comment: So if I use an OS that doesn't need that, I'll be good without it, right?

Comment: for any modern OS i would imagine so. why do you want to disable it?

Comment: faster boots