# USB Keyboard won't work after Post but before OS loads

Tags: keyboard, bios, computer-building, post

On my new build I just installed Windows 7 x64 and realized that I had put it on the wrong partition. I pop my OS CD back to re-install. My keyboard will work to access the BIOS but when the little message comes up to "press any key to boot from CD..." I can't do anything! If I let it go ahead and boot Windows it will work.

What I have tried:

- Clearing the CMOS by hitting the button on the back of my computer.
- I tried a different USB keyboard but it didn't work either.
- I tried using one of those USB/PS2 adapters but I had the same problem.

Any other ideas what to try? I'm about out!

Comment: I haven't experienced that, but a possible workaround to try, you could try a PS2 keyboard, they work a bit differently, you may notice that with a a ps2 keyboard they flash as soon as they are plugged in, so a slight sign of them working when plugged in!  I doubt it'd work. But worth a try. It looks like maybe it's not a ps2 or usb issue. I'm not entirely sure whether that "press any key to boot from CD." is from the BIOS or the CD, I think it's from the CD, though that doesn't help.

Comment: But to install windows you could just make it so it can't boot the current windows off the hard disk  .  Remove the current one , or make the partition of the current one inactive.

Comment: have you disabled [Legacy USB](http://superuser.com/questions/207150/why-shouldnt-i-disable-legacy-usb-on-a-laptop) in the BIOS?

Comment: Side note - that message "press any key to boot from CD" - it's from the CD.  It's Windows way of trying to prevent you from booting off the install CD again after Setup invokes a reboot after the initial phase of the install.

Comment: @Xantec: ENABLING that setting proved to be the solution.

Comment: @Icode4food: glad to hear it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to enable the "enable legacy USB keyboard support" in the bios.

I think that it actually didn't work the first time like I thought it did. My theory is that what happened then was that there wasn't anything bootable other than the CD so it automatically booted to that.

I'm not sure why I had to do this but it work so I can't complain!